# Алгоритм LZSS C#

Tags: c#

Мне нужно написать алгоритм для кодирования и декодирования текста методом LZSS.Попробовал реализовать его так, как я понял. Но декод у меня неправильный получается, не знаю, где ошибка. Я вводил "This is sample text to compress".Код получился такой: This (2,1)(4,1)(4,1)(8,1)ple(4,1)(15,1)(17,1)(17,1)(16,1)(23,1)pr(18,1)(31,1). А декод такой:This i   ple pr.

```
public class LZSSEncoder
{
    public string Encode(string text, int windowSize)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return string.Empty;

        List<string> dictionary = new List<string>();
        string encodedText = string.Empty;
        int currentIndex = 0;

        while (currentIndex < text.Length)
        {
            int matchLength = 0;
            int matchIndex = -1;

            for (int i = currentIndex - windowSize; i < currentIndex; i++)
            {
                if (i >= 0 && i + matchLength < currentIndex && text.Substring(i, matchLength + 1) == text.Substring(currentIndex, matchLength + 1))
                {
                    matchLength++;
                    matchIndex = i;
                }
            }

            if (matchLength > 0)
            {
                encodedText += $"({matchIndex},{matchLength})";
                currentIndex += matchLength + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                encodedText += text[currentIndex];
                dictionary.Add(encodedText[currentIndex].ToString());
                currentIndex++;
            }

            if (dictionary.Count > windowSize)
                dictionary.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        return encodedText;
    }
}
public class LZSSDecoder
{
    public string Decode(string encodedText, int windowSize)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodedText))
            return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder decodedText = new StringBuilder();
        int currentIndex = 0;
        List<string> dictionary = new List<string>();

        while (currentIndex < encodedText.Length)
        {
            if (encodedText[currentIndex] == '(')
            {
                int commaIndex = encodedText.IndexOf(',', currentIndex);
                int startIndex = int.Parse(encodedText.Substring(currentIndex + 1, commaIndex - currentIndex - 1));
                int closingParenthesisIndex = encodedText.IndexOf(')', commaIndex);
                int length = int.Parse(encodedText.Substring(commaIndex + 1, closingParenthesisIndex - commaIndex - 1));

                int startIndexInDecodedText = decodedText.Length - windowSize + startIndex;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    if (startIndexInDecodedText >= 0 && startIndexInDecodedText < decodedText.Length)
                    {
                        decodedText.Append(decodedText[startIndexInDecodedText]);
                        startIndexInDecodedText++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Проверяем, находится ли индекс в пределах списка dictionary
                        if (startIndex + i < dictionary.Count)
                        {
                            string dictionaryEntry = dictionary[startIndex + i];
                            decodedText.Append(dictionaryEntry);
                            dictionary.Add(dictionaryEntry);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Обрабатываем случай, когда индекс выходит за пределы списка dictionary
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                currentIndex = closingParenthesisIndex + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                decodedText.Append(encodedText[currentIndex]);
                dictionary.Add(encodedText[currentIndex].ToString());
                currentIndex++;
            }

            if (dictionary.Count > windowSize)
                dictionary.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        return decodedText.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Навскидку проблему не вижу, попробуйте в отладчике по шагам пройти, или вы хотите, чтобы за вас это кто-то сделал? А вообще у вас и кодировщик работает неправильно, он по одному символы копирует, хотя `"is "` должно копироваться сразу как три символа за один раз, а не три раза по одному символу, так вы ничего не упакуете, а только раздуете данные наоборот. Ну тут только отладкой разбираться, что с индексами не то получается. Может названия переменных где перепутали, может где индексацию не совсем чётко сделали.

Comment: Кстати, какой текст вводите вы показали, а используемый вами размер окна `windowSize` не показали. А нужно все данные показывать, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: Поищите книгу Брюс Шнайер - "Прикладная криптография", Там даже примеры на С есть. Это конечно не ответ, но вдруг поможет?